# problems showing the actual URL of a page in my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsurl

I'm making an iPad browser, and I have a little problem. When I go to google, for example, I write the google direction in a `textField`. The problem is that when I change the web page, it still says `http://www.google.com/`. Here's my code:

```
-(IBAction)buttonpressed2:(id)sender {

    url = [NSURL URLWithString:[textField text]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [webView isEqual:textField.text];
}
```

How can I make the `textField` show the page that I'm watching right now, and not the first url typed in the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure when you set up the webView, you assign the `UIWebViewDelegate` to `self`

Then, implement the delegate method: `webViewDidFinishLoad`, as such:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSURLRequest *currentRequest = [webView request];
    NSURL *currentURL = [currentRequest URL];

    //This will log the current url
    NSLog(@"Current URL is %@", currentURL.absoluteString);

    //Then to display it in the textField
    textfield.text = currentURL.absoluteString;
 }
```

**Edit:**

A delegate is a special set of methods that wait for an event to happen.  When that event happens, the appropiate method is called.  The method above is one of the delegate methods for a `UIWebView` - When a specific event happens with the webView, in this case when the `webViewDidFinishLoad`, that method is automtically called and we can respond as such.  In order to set the delegate, we can proceed one of two ways:

1. If you created the webView in code, this is with something like this:

   ```
   UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init...]
   ```

   then all you need to do is add the following line of code:

   ```
   webView.delegate = self;
   ```
2. However, you might have also created the webView in the interface builder - If that's the case, click on the webView and the linker tab, and drag the delegate option over to "File's Owner".

and thats it.

Comment: Thank u guys! You have helped me a lot, I really didnt know what I had to do. I think that you also should know that you have helped a 15 yrs old developer :)

Comment: No problem.  Since the answer helped, would you mind checking the green arrow next to my answer.  That gives me points for a good answer and you points for asking a question (It also marks the question as answered). you can also hit the up arrow above the 0 if it was a good answer.  PS. I'm also 16 years old

Comment: Also, check out raywenderlich.com.  He writes terriffic tutorials for beginners to experts.  He is even starting a series of tutorials for High School Students

Comment: +1 from me, you will have to wait for @user1131097 to get more rep in order to upvote.  They can however, mark the check to accept your answer.

Comment: thank you a lot man! I'm asking myself if u could explain to me how i have to implement the UIWebViewDelegate, i don't know nothing about protocols and this stuff

Comment: Sure I can, would it help if I explained delegates in general, or how to implement the UIWebView delegate

Comment: For now I will be fine if you just explain UIWebView delegate, it's all I need!

Comment: Please answer as early you can

Comment: Ok ok I'm so close to it. Just one more thing: when I write web.delegate =self; Xcode says:Passing 'ViewController*const_strong to parameter of incompatible type 'id<UIWebViewDelegate>'

Comment: did you ad the delegate to the header fille?  To do that, go to ViewController.h and after this: `UIViewController`, add `<UIWebViewDelegate>`

Comment: Ah! OK! NOW IT WORKS! Thank you so much, I have been trying to make it work! And now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Your class should implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol.  Then in the method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` you can do this:

```
[textField setText:[[request URL] absoluteString]];
```

This way the value in the textField will be updated whenever you navigate to a new url.